# Get the year out of timestamp sql

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a problem extracting the year out of a mysql timestamp field. I managed to get it work with a **datetime field** using this method:

```
SELECT id FROM TABLE WHERE YEAR(creation_date) = 2010

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pub_media` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` text,
  `filename` text,
  `path` text,
  `serv_path` text,
  `type` enum('images','videos','files','audio','gallery') DEFAULT NULL,
  `keywords` text,
  `label_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `update_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `rank` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Server version : 5.1.41
Is there a simalar way to perform this action on a timestamp field? I want to keep this action in my SQL statement and not try to move it to PHP or any other scripting language, if possible.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What problem are you encountering, and can you include the output of `CREATE TABLE` in your question?  This works for me on MySQL 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.3:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table1`;

CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `ts` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO table1 (id) VALUES (1);

SELECT * FROM table1;
+----+---------------------+
| id | ts                  |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2010-07-05 15:32:11 |
+----+---------------------+

SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE YEAR(ts) = 2010;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
```

Comment: heck no, I don't know why it ain't working on my DB. Maybe because I use MyISAM instead of InnoDB as the DB Engine?

Comment: I've just tried it with MyISAM, and that works too. Can you edit your question, and include the output from `CREATE TABLE <table>`? Also, what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: It works as I would expect with your table structure. I've just copied and pasted it into my copy of MySQL, inserted a record, and selected from it with no need for casting or conversion.

Comment: As we are both using MySQL 5.1.41, that is very odd. Do you get an error message, or just an empty result set?

Comment: dude , it fricking works.. I tried it again using my phpmyadmin and there it worked fine.. I really haven't got a clue about what I was doing wrong..

Comment: It doesn't work on my system, that was the first thing I tried, and it returned zero results!
doing "SELECT YEAR(ts) FROM table1" does return the correct information, but putting the "YEAR(ts)" in the WHERE clause returns nothing... Maybe it's a collation thing?

Comment: odd, just messed around with my query, tried again, and hey-presto, it now works with "WHERE YEAR(ts) = '2010'"... most odd!

Comment: "Stranger and stranger," said Alice. I tried it with and without quotes around the year, and both worked.

Comment: This answer produces different results based on where you are logging in from, because of timezones

Answer (score 16):

Extract year from date or timestamp in more portable way:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM creation_date) = 2010
```

Works with MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle...

Answer (score 8):

use `CAST` function :)

`SELECT id FROM TABLE WHERE YEAR(CAST(creation_date AS DATE))=2010`

should work with creation_date timestamp

[[edit]] ,added () around cast

Comment: I'm getting this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'creation_date AS DATE) = 2010 AND deleted = 0 ORDER BY rank DESC' at line 1

using this query:
SELECT id,title FROM pub_media WHERE YEAR(CAST creation_date AS DATE) = 2010 AND deleted = 0 ORDER BY rank DESC

mysql v. 5.1.41

Comment: This solution works , but using just the YEAR function works to , see approved answer post

Answer (score 7):

In my case cast() did not work. from_unixtime() did though. The query would be the following one:

```
SELECT id FROM TABLE WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(creation_date)) = 2010
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works ok,

```
SELECT id FROM TABLE WHERE DATE_FORMAT( creation_date,  "%Y" ) = "2010"
```

Formatting the data is really useful for queries like this, I have used it numerous times for breaking data down to 10 minute intervals for example...

Comment: than someone should do a speedtest on what is the fastest, using DATE_FORMAT or TYPE cast.. :p

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 where year(ts) = 2016 and month(ts) = 9
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.