# How to select only year from datetimestamp

Tags: sql

I want to populate my table's column with only year from datetimestamp.

I am using the below query:

```
date_format(df.startyear,'yyy') as startyear,
```

But this is returning null values.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: Maybe useful: [Get the year out of timestamp sql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3180086/3184785)

Answer (score 1):

Given your initial attempt to use `DATE_FORMAT`, I suspect you're using `MySQL`. If accurate you can retrieve the `YEAR` in a couple of ways.

**Using [`YEAR`](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_year.asp)**

```
YEAR(df.startyear) AS startyear
```

**Using [`EXTRACT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_extract.asp)**

```
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM df.startyear) AS startyear
```

Comment: insert overwrite table abcd select(startyear from df)....could you please help me write the query in this syntax. I am populating the startyear column from a df where startyear is having the value in datetimestamp and i only want the year from it

Comment: @Noname -- `insert overwrite table abcd select year(startyear) from df`  -- just enclose the timestamp column with `year(...)`

Comment: i tried but it didn't help

Comment: and could you please suggest that if i want to populate column c2 with column c1's year(which is extracted from C1's datetimestamp) by incrementing the year by 1, how can i do that?
suppose for cq year is 2020 so for c2 i want 2021